# Stub geocoder with address_components in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

i try to write rspec to test some code work with gem [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder). With `location` is a `Geocoder::Result::Google` object, my code like :

```
address = location.address_components_of_type(:sublocality_level_1).first&.dig('long_name')
```

and i implement stub a point like (refer [here](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#testing-apps-that-use-geocoder) ) : 
```ruby

```
Geocoder.configure(lookup: :test)
Geocoder::Lookup::Test.set_default_stub(
  [
    {
      'latitude'     => 35.6691084,
      'longitude'    => 139.6009546,
      'address'      => 'Address',
      'state'        => 'State',
      'city'         => 'City',
      'types'        => ['political'],
      'address_components' => [
        {
          'types' => ['sublocality_level_1'],
          'long_name' => 'level_1',
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
)
```

i try to byebug when run rspec and check, i get :

```
(byebug) location.class
Geocoder::Result::Test
(byebug) location.address_components
[{"types"=>["sublocality_level_1"], "long_name"=>"level_1"}]
(byebug) location.respond_to?(:address_components_of_type)
false
```

`location.respond_to?(:address_components_of_type)` return false, and i can't call `location.address_components_of_type(:sublocality_level_1).first&.dig('long_name')` as my expect.

`location` when run rspec is a `Geocoder::Result::Test` object

so, can you help me to resolve this issue? many thanks

---

Geocoder version: 1.4.3
Rails version: 5.0.2

Comment: is `address` a string? Why not to use `address = location. address_components[0]['long_name']`?

Comment: this is simple ex, main point that i want to stub object have method  `address_components_of_type` @Thanh

Comment: `Geocoder::Result::Test` does not have method [address_components_of_type](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/results/test.rb), so you need to implement it, like this: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/results/google.rb#L112

Comment: many thanks, i'll try to do it @Thanh